# Salesforce SOQL : is it possible to get percentage of two field in soql query

Tags: soql

SELECT ValueX,ValueY, percent(valueX / ValueY) from Object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use math in `Percent SOQL` statements. You have to do the math in Apex Code.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a formula fields that calculate it and select it

Comment: While this is technically a complete answer, I think it would be improved if you would share an example of how this could end up looking (what is the formula? how would you query it?)

Comment: A formula field is a type of attribute, in which you can specify a formula similar to excel's. To query it, is as queryint a text field. Any SF developer ahould know how to query it. Long before that, he should know how to create the field. It is an answer to the question, that solves the problem in a different way, but achieving the same.

Comment: You should make this part of the answer by making an [edit].

Comment: I see no point in that. The answer says everything that any SF developer should already know. It is impossible to get into developing without knowing what a formula is. It is one of the first things, that you learn fhow to query a field. This is so basic, that it makes absolutely no sense to go any deeper into detail.